# How to delete an element from a std::vector of std::pair based on .first value?

Tags: c++, stdvector, std-pair

Ok so I have a sorted `std::vector<std::pair<int,double>>`. What I can't seem to find out is how can I delete an entry from the vector based on the value of the "first" element of the std::pair (int). I will potentially do this numerous times in my algo, so I'd rather not iterate through the vector everytime (which may contain upto a million entries). I know we can easily remove elements based on the index using std::erase or remove, but is there a way to do it based on the value of the first element of the pair? Or can we get the index of that element and then use std::erase?

Note: the value of the first element of the std::pair is unique for the vector. Given the constraints of the program, I need to use the vector (i.e can't use map or different container).

Example: I have a container as such:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,double>> vec = { {20, 60.3}, ... {10, -20.2}, {1020, -80.9}};
```

I want to quickly remove the element with the first element == 10 from the vector, but I don't know at which index of the vector it is located.

Comment: [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) has an example, modify it to reach your needs.

Comment: You can find the (index of) element by binary search in logarithmic time complexity. But erasing that from vector, in any case, will be a linear operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your vector is sorted, so you can (and should) use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`.

These give you a *range* matching some criterion (provided the container's sort order makes this meaningful), and does so via a nice binary search.

Provide a custom comparator that only examines the first item of each pair.

---

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,double>> data = { {20, 60.3}, {10, -20.2}, {1020, -80.9}};
    
    const int intToSearchFor = 10;
    
    const auto lower = std::lower_bound(
       data.begin(),
       data.end(),
       intToSearchFor,
       [](const std::pair<int, double>& el, const int i)
       {
          return el.first < i;
       }
    );
    
    const auto upper = std::upper_bound(
       data.begin(),
       data.end(),
       intToSearchFor,
       [](const int i, const std::pair<int, double>& el)
       {
          return i < el.first;
       }
    );
    
    data.erase(lower, upper);
}
```

If your `int`s are unique, you don't need the upper bound check, and can just erase the element at position `lower` … but you'll have to first ensure that it's *actually* equal to `i` (it could be greater-than), and also that it isn't `data.end()`.

---

This algorithm basically implements `std::map::erase` (or `std::multimap::erase`) but with sorted data in contiguous storage. It's great for fast lookup of relatively small datasets; unfortunately, *you're stuck with the cost of shuffling subsequent elements down after an erasure*. Maps avoid this by storing data indirectly. A deque might be a good middle ground for you. Only you can know, based on your normal data and access patterns.

You may also find that, because the element type is just a `pair<int, double>`, your compiler may exchange a whole load of `operator=` calls for a nice simple `memmove`, which is plenty fast at the scale you're talking about nowadays.